# Snapping points from layer to line in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, snapping

I need to snap the points to the lines in another layer in order to create another line shapefile.

Is there any plugin / tool available for this? 
The Snap geometries doesn't take points as a reference layer.

Answer (score 3):

An option would be to look into the SAGA Tools in the `Processing Toolbox`. There is a Snap Points to Lines tool, which should accomplish what you are looking for. You can search for it in the Processing Toolbox by typing "Snap" or navigating:

```
SAGA -> Vector Point Tools -> Snap points to lines
```

It allows you to define the input points layer, a search distance and whether the output is in memory or a new shapefile layer.

Comment: Hi. My qgis version is 2.14.19.  What version is yours? I don't have that tool under the saga 2.3.2. Thank you

Comment: I was looking at my version. It is 2.18.13 and SAGA 2.3.2. I would update your question to include the version details. It will allow other people to add their answers based on the information provided. I am not familiar with 2.14, perhaps someone else can assist. Or, you upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: I'm using QGIS 3.28.3 and this actually still works nicely, even though using the tool gives the following warning: 'SAGA version 7.8.2 is not officially supported'

Comment: Another option is to use `Processing Toolbox > Vector geometry > Snap geometries to layer`